# How to add percentage label on top of bar chart from a data frame with different sum total data groups

Tags: python-3.x

I am new in coding with python, I am trying to develop a bar chart with percentage on top. I have a sample data frame Quiz2. I developed code and gives only 1600% at first single bar. Kindly any one with help how can i do it correct?

```
#Approach 2
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
sns.set()
%matplotlib inline
Quiz2 = pd.DataFrame({'Kaha': ['16', '5'], 'Shiny': ['16', '10']}) 
data=Quiz2 .rename(index={0: "Male", 1: "Female"})
data=data.astype(float)
Q1p = data[['Kaha','Shiny']].plot(kind='bar',  figsize=(5, 5), legend=True, fontsize=12)
Q1p.set_xlabel("Gender", fontsize=12)
Q1p.set_ylabel("Number of people", fontsize=12)
#Q1p.set_xticklabels(x_labels)

for p in Q1p.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    height = p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    Q1p.annotate(f'{height:.0%}', (x + width/2, y + height*1.02), ha='center')
    plt.show()
```

I want the percentage of Kaha (with 21 sum total) to appear as (76.2% for Male and 23.8% for Female) and that of shy (with 26 sum total) as (61.5% for Male and 38.5%for Female). Kindly requesting help

Comment: Are you really faithfully duplicating the answers as provided?  Or are you doing something differently?  Also, it would be nice if you provided a sample data set which could be used to analyze the issues.

Comment: What i presented above is my code + references  where i tried to  adapt the labeling of   % value on top bar, it is not a duplicate of original  but i seem unable to resolve some errors, Hence seeking help, Quiz2 is my data reference

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the dataframe you are working with, so we can evaluate

Comment: Never mind my comment about input, I see you have provided the dataframe build statement.

Comment: In approach 1 there is a formatting error in your code ```plt.show()}
                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: unmatched '}'```

Answer (score 0):

In approach 2, the reason you have only 1 value displaying is the `plt.show()`
should be outdented so it comes after the processing of the for loop.  You are getting a value of 1600% because you are plotting the value as the height of the bar in the line beginning with `Q1p.annotate(f'{height:.0%}'` Instead of height this should be height/10*total or something to give you the percentage.

Here is a solution, but not sure if I am computing the percentages correctly:

```
Quiz2 = pd.DataFrame({'Kaha': ['16', '5'], 'Shiny': ['16', '10']}) 
data=Quiz2 .rename(index={0: "Male", 1: "Female"})
data=data.astype(float)
total = len(data)*10
Q1p = data[['Kaha','Shiny']].plot(kind='bar',  figsize=(5, 5), legend=True, fontsize=12)
Q1p.set_xlabel("Gender", fontsize=12)
Q1p.set_ylabel("Number of people", fontsize=12)
#Q1p.set_xticklabels(x_labels)

for p in Q1p.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    height = p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    Q1p.annotate(f'{height/total:.0%}', (x + width/2, y + height*1.02), ha='center')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Dear itrorh66 thanks for kind consideration and valuable comments you made from above, (1) i removed the formatting error plt.show()} in last row of first approach , the last } was added during pasting the code here, but it s not in my Code  (2) Each approach above contains a data frame Quiz2 (3) The help from your code is very valuable.but the percentage of "Kaha"  from the legend should sum to 100 (currently sums (80+25)=105, also percentage of   Shiny should sum 100 (currently sums (80+50)=130.

Comment: What i noted from your suggestion is that  the data in Quiz2 have different length Kaha sums to 21 (16+5) and Shiny sums to 26 (16+10) , if i change the total to; total = (len(data)+1)*7 then the Kaha percentage prints correctly as 76%for male  and 24% for female. Is it possible to use different total length in each bar group because  the Shiny total is supposed to be;  total = (len(data)*13 for this approach

Comment: As I sad in my post, I didn't think the percentages were correct, the lines to be changed include: ```total = len(data)*10``` and the ```f'{height/total:.0%}'``` segment of ```Q1p.annotate(f'{height/total:.0%}', (x + width/2, y + height*1.02), ha='center')```.  You may need to figure a way to compute separate totals for each type of data male, female and use the different totals to determine your percentages

Comment: @ itprorh66  note that i improved the question to point exactly on the problem and i removed my prior approaches . I have not succeeded yet